# Thread error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value and

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

It shows this error while i am trying to run my app..

```
func loadChecklistItems()

{
    let path = dataFilePath()

    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)

    {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
        {
           let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data)

          items = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("ChecklistsItems") as! [ChecklistItem]

            unarchiver.finishDecoding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line does the error happens?

Comment: Errors occurs at:                                                                                      item = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("ChecklistsItems") as! [ChecklistItem]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("ChecklistsItems") as! [ChecklistItem]
```

You need to check if your decoded object is of type ChecklistItem:

```
    if let checkListItems = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("ChecklistsItems") as? [ChecklistItem]{
        items = checkListItems
    } else {
         // Perhaps, you need to inform about some kind of error
    }
```

Comment: So I had to change that line and make it as an unwrapped.

Comment: Thanks @agy...It works. But whats the actual problem with this?